# Generalized estimating equations working by themselves but not within functions (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to run GEE using the geepack package. It works fine "on its own" but not within a function, please see example below:

```
library(geepack)
library(pstools)

df <- data.frame(study_id = c(1:20),
                 leptin = runif(20),
                 insulin = runif(20),
                 age = runif(20, min = 20, max = 45),
                 sex = sample(c(0,1), size = 20, replace = TRUE))

#Works
geepack::geeglm(leptin ~ insulin + age + sex, id = study_id, data = df)

#Doesn't work
model_function_covariates_gee <- function(x,y) {
  M1 <- paste0(x, "~", y, "+ age + sex")
  M1_fit <- geepack::geeglm(M1, id = study_id, data = df)
  s <- summary(M1_fit)
  return(s)
}

model_function_covariates_gee("leptin", "insulin")
```

Error message:

```
Error in mcall$formula[3] <- switch(match(length(sformula), c(0, 2, 3)),  : 
  incompatible types (from language to character) in subassignment type fix
```

Does anyone know why this is? I've fiddled around with it but can't get it to change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `geeglm` requires a formula as its first argument, not a character.  So try `M1 <- as.formula(paste0(x, "~", y, "+ age + sex"))`.

Comment: Ah, amazing, that worked, thanks so much.

Comment: All I did was read the online documentation.  Try it some time! ;)